# Changing shipped via text in WooCommerce orders and emails for specific shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, shipping-method

I am trying to change the shipped via in emails and in order information.  I have a custom radio button with customer fields that are filled out only on the checkout page.  Currently WooCommerce takes the label of the radio button but not the fields.

I would like to have the fields only in customer email and in the order information under woocommerce -> orders -> order#.

I can get it to change to text but lost on how to include the custom fields on a new line, which are `carrier_name` and `carrier_number` - these are the only fields that should show in both email and order information under WooCommerce.

The `carrier_name` and `carrier_number` are only available from the checkout page, not the cart page. When the 'Custom Carrier' is not selected it should print in email the correct shipping method, which I think it does by default but just wanted to include the requirement.

The third image shows the order information under woocommerce > orders > order#, this should show only `carrier_name` and `carrier_number`.

My code:

```
//adjusting emails to show custom carrier name and number
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_shipping_to_display_shipped_via', 'wdo_remove_shipping_label_thnakyou_page_cart', 10, 2 );
function wdo_remove_shipping_label_thnakyou_page_cart($label, $method) {
    $shipping_label = get_post_meta($order->id, 'carrier_name') ;
    $shipping_label = 'Just Test!!!';
    return $shipping_label;
}
```

**1 The Carrier Info I want to show, under Custom Carrier**

[image: 1 The Carrier Info I want to show, under Custom Carrier]

**2 What I can currently get to send in email**

[image: 2 What I can currently get to send in email]

**3 Order Information from woocommerce -> orders -> order#**

[image: 3 Order Information from woocommerce -> orders -> order#]

**4 Order information without the code I put in**, I changed the label using php code on checkout page different from cart page  "Custom Carrier (Enter Details Next Page)" to  checkout page "Custom Carrier":

[image: 4 Order information without the code I put in, I changed the label using php code on checkout page different from cart page "Custom Carrier (Enter Details Next Page)" to checkout page "Custom Carrier"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code like for example wrong function arguments… 
Try the following instead:

```
// Adjusting order and emails "shipping via" to show custom carrier name and number
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_shipping_to_display_shipped_via', 'wdo_filter_order_shipping_to_display_shipped_via', 10, 2 );
function wdo_filter_order_shipping_to_display_shipped_via( $shipped_via, $order ) {
    $carrier_name = $order->get_meta('carrier_name'); // Get carrier name

    // Targeting orders with defined "carrier name" for "Custom Carrier" shipping method
    if ( $carrier_name ) {
        $carrier_number = $order->get_meta('carrier_number'); // get carrier number
        $shipped_via = '&nbsp;<small class="shipped_via">' . sprintf( __( 'via Custom Carrier: %s (%s)', 'woocommerce' ), $carrier_name, $carrier_number ) . '</small>';
    }
    return $shipped_via;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

---

**Important note (update):**

[Change specific shipping method title on WooCommerce orders after checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65754067/change-specific-shipping-method-title-on-woocommerce-orders-after-checkout) answer code replace this answer as it handle the change everywhere **including on admin edit orders pages too** and it's a much **lightweight solution**.

Comment: Works great for the checkout page and the email!!  Only missing is the order info which is still showing the "Custom Carrier (Enter Details Next Page)" on the order# under woocommerce > orders > ...

any thoughts?  Pic 3 in original thread